# Does SQL Server have a reference partitioning equivalent?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, partitioning, oracle-11g, feature-comparison

Oracle 11g has introduced a new feature that is called Reference Partition.

Using reference partitioning, a child table can inherit the partitioning characteristics from a parent table.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Reference_partitioning

Is there an equivalent feature in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly.

In SQL Server, you create a [partition function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx) and a [partition scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179854.aspx), which are objects separate from the tables themselves, which define the partitioning characteristics. Then, tables are [created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) referencing the partition scheme.

So, yes, there is a central definition of the partitioning characteristics, but the reference is made to the *partition scheme* (which could be anything), not to any particular *table* or relationship.

Comment: Note that table and index partitioning is only available in the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server (and thus also in the Developer and Enterprise Evaluation editions). References: [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.100).aspx), [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx).